# Java disassemble a String containing a method header in Components

Tags: java, parsing

Is there way to parse a String containing a method header like:

```java
public static int calculate(int a, int b)
```

into the components

- Access modifier (public, protected, private)
- Non-Access modifier (static, abstract)
- Return type
- Method name
- List of parameters

or do I have to program this by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) library to extract this information.
With Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
    <version>${javaparser.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, declare a parser instance and the body to parse. Please note that you have to postfix you input with `{}` in order to comply with a valid method declaration.

```
JavaParser parser = new JavaParser();

String body = "public static int calculate(int a, int b){}";
ParseResult<BodyDeclaration<?>> result = parser.parseBodyDeclaration(body);
if (result.isSuccessful()) {
    BodyDeclaration<?> bodyDeclaration = result.getResult().get();
}
```

Afterwards, validate that it is a method declaration to apply a downcast to `MethodDeclaration`. Finally, you can extract the necessary information.

```
if (bodyDeclaration.isMethodDeclaration()) {
    MethodDeclaration method = (MethodDeclaration) bodyDeclaration;

    // [public, static]
    NodeList<Modifier> modifiers = method.getModifiers();
    // int
    Type type = method.getType();
    // calculate
    SimpleName name = method.getName();
    // [int a, int b]
    NodeList<Parameter> parameters = method.getParameters();
}
```